# issue with windowless rendering on Chrome v 25.0.1364.97 m

Tags: google-chrome, firebreath

The latest update to Chrome (25.0.1364.97 m) seems to have messed up support for windowless rendering in my FireBreath plugin (FireBreath v1.7). To check whether or not my code was the problem, I tried FBTestPlugin with the following HTML code:

```
<object id="plugin0" type="application/x-fbtestplugin" width="300" height="300">
    <param name="windowless" value="true" />
</object><br />
<object id="plugin1" type="application/x-fbtestplugin" width="300" height="300">
</object><br />"
```

The windowless plugin (`id="plugin0"`) doesn't render in Chrome; the windowed one (`id="plugin1"`) does. Both are fine in Firefox and IE. The issue occurs on winXP and win7 x86, not sure about other platforms.

Is this a bug in Chrome? or in FireBreath? Really hoping someone with more knowledge than me about browser plugins may be able to offer some advice.

**UPDATE:**
The same issue I was having with my FireBreath plugin (colours being messed up when blitting to the screen) is reported at https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=178598. There is a workaround suggested in that post, which is to set the background colour of the plugin `<object>` or the parent container to black. Happily, I tried that, and it's working for now.

Comment: You could provide an answer with what you've found. (answering yourself is fine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in the update to my original question, I found a suitable workaround at  https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=178598. Chrome appears to be misinterpreting some of the RGB pixel data as an alpha channel (transparency), so the colours rendered to the screen in my FireBreath plugin get mixed up. The workaround is to set the background colour of the plugin object to black (`background-color: #000000;`) (either in the css file or the `object` tag itself).

Another workaround is to switch to windowed plugins (the problem only occurs with windowless), but that introduces other issues (such as the need to render from a separate thread etc.).

By the way, the code used to render pixel data to the screen was derived from the example at https://gist.github.com/taxilian/1099740.